# What causes a civilization to be unable to accept an embassy?

Tags: civilization-5

I started a new game with Japan on immortal difficulty, and in the trade screen I can accept their embassy in my capital but they can't accept mine (that option is gray). Why is that?

Comment: Didn't discover writing, please delete my question

Comment: You can either self delte the question or answer it yourself with the answer you found yourself :)

Comment: How can I delete my question?

Comment: There should be share, edit, delete, flag links in the lower left corner of your question.

Comment: I see only share, edit and flag.

Comment: Strange, I see share, edit, close, delete, flag on my own posts.

Comment: Only registered accounts can self-delete questions. In this case, though, self-deletion is probably not the best answer; more people may come along in the future confused by the same thing, so the route of getting a correct, detailed, and accepted answer is probably better.

Comment: I don't see any reason to delete the question in this case for the reasons Billy Mailman mentioned.

Answer (score 7):

I needed to research writing first. I usually start from a later era, that's why I never experienced this issue before.